# Eclipse Juno can't run any Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, jre

I use Eclipse Juno - Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers  , and I can't run any Java project , mean even there is no "Run" option  .

For example when I right click on the Main class I just see (no "Run") -

[image]

I use `jdk1.7.0_17` and `jre7` and they both locates at  -

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

My `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable point on `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17;`   .

Using Win7 .

I could run java before until I added [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) extension for the Eclipse .

Any solution please ?

**Edit:**

That's what has under "Run configurations"  -

[image]

Could it be this Eclipse version isn't provide Java running  ?

Comment: what happens if you highlight the project ('Test') instead of the specific .java file you want to run? also do you have all the code locally? I ask since you installed egit.

Comment: 1. Gives same options  . 2. locally

Comment: do you have "Build Automatically" checked in the run menu (I believe its the run menu, but poke around).

Comment: @FrankThomas: see my edit please  .